# React JS htaccess routing issue

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess

The application I made with React was told that I should direct everything to index.html.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ index \ .html $ - [L]
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -F
RewriteRule. /index.html [L]
```

That's how it works.

I've done a management panel on this website but with php.

So when I enter example.com/adminPanel also goes to index.html.

How to fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude /adminPanel request from rule

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ index \ .html $ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/adminPanel
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}! -F
RewriteRule. /index.html [L]
```

Comment: If you enter example.com/adminPanel.php it's work or not?